# F# query: find rows with max value in each group

Tags: database, f#, entity-framework-core, computation-expression

In my project I use:

- F# with query workflow
- Entity Framework Core 3.11
- MS SQL

I have a problem similar to this one: [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column), but I'm wondering how to express the SQL presented in that question using F# query workflow:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.rev, a.contents
FROM YourTable a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(rev) rev
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY id
) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.rev = b.rev
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Direct translation

For a direct translation, the inner query is:

```ml
let innerQuery =
    query {
        for inner in ctx.YourTable do
        groupBy inner.id into grp
        select (grp.Key, grp.Max(fun ent -> ent.rev))
    }
```

And then, in theory, I think the full query should be:

```ml
query {
    for outer in ctx.YourTable do
    join inner in innerQuery
        on ((outer.id, outer.rev) = inner)
    select outer
}
```

However, that doesn't work:

```
Type mismatch when building 'ty': function type doesn't match delegate type. Expected

'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[Program+YourTable,System.Tuple`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]'

, but received type

'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[Program+YourTable,Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.AnonymousObject`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]'.
```

I could be wrong, or it could be a bug/limitation. Perhaps someone has a workaround.

### Alternate translation

However, if you'll accept a slightly different translation, it does work:

```ml
query {
    for outer in ctx.YourTable do
    where (
        query {
            for inner in ctx.YourTable do
            groupBy inner.id into grp
            exists (grp.Key = outer.id && grp.Max(fun ent -> ent.rev) = outer.rev)
        })
    select outer
}
```

The generated SQL is:

```sql
SELECT [y].[id], [y].[rev], [y].[contents]
FROM [YourTable] AS [y]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [YourTable] AS [y0]
    GROUP BY [y0].[id]
    HAVING ([y0].[id] = [y].[id]) AND (MAX([y0].[rev]) = [y].[rev]))
```

Output is:

```
{ id = 2
  rev = 1
  contents = "..." }
{ id = 1
  rev = 3
  contents = "..." }
```

Note that I had to set a composite primary key of `id, rev` when building the model:

```ml
override __.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder: ModelBuilder) =
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourTable>()
        .HasKey([| "id"; "rev" |]) |> ignore
```

Full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/brianberns/9f1ca0154f2bf5619e8e1d7963fbf41b).

Comment: No idea where you are, but I will look for you. I will find you and then I will buy you coffee. Many thanks!

Comment: Quick update from my side: I extended the idea and had to groupBy two columns. The way to do this in F# is:

```
let key = AnonymousObject<_,_>(inner.Col1, inner.Col2)
groupValBy inner key into g
```